# Error in prisma when using connectOrCreate

Tags: javascript, prisma

Does anyone know what does this error mean in Prisma?

`EnvVarNotFound("Expected parent binding \'7\' to be present.")`

It happens after I use `connectOrCreate` on my payload, but it works fine with `create` or `connect` :/

Not sure, why this error occurs after I use `connectOrCreate`, am I missing something here?

Sample Code:

```
prisma.create({
  "data": {
    "unitOfMeasurement": {
        "connectOrCreate": {
            "where": {
                "name": "PC"
            },
            "create": {
                "name": "PC"
            }
        }
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking you schema to be the following:

```
model Parent {
  id                  Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  uof                 UnitOfMeasurement? @relation(fields: [unitOfMeasurementId], references: [id])
  unitOfMeasurementId Int?
}

model UnitOfMeasurement {
  id   Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String  @unique
  a    Parent?
}
```

I ran the below query on version *2.11.0* of `@prisma/cli` and `@prisma/client` and it works fine.

```
await prisma.parent.create({
    data: {
      uof: {
        connectOrCreate: { create: { name: 'PC' }, where: { name: 'PC' } },
      },
    },
})
```

You might be facing an issue related to an older version or a mismatch in versions of `@prisma/client` and `@prisma/cli`. Could you try the latest version, run `prisma generate` and check again?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, This works well on my end too—I guess the problem is I'm using my name as an ID in my schema. Last question, how do you do this for multiple items?

Comment: I tried it with keeping `name` as ID (removed the `id` field) and it still works. Also for creating multiple items, you would need to have a 1-many relation. In that case, just pass an array to `connectOrCreate`. Something like: `connectOrCreate: [{ create: { name: 'PC' }, where: { name: 'PC' } },{ create: { name: 'PD' }, where: { name: 'PD' } }]`

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on why this is the accepted answer as I am also having the same issue? Best I can tell, these seem to be same query minus the 'prisma.parent'.

Comment: @Krejko you would need to share more details as I would need to reproduce it. There can be diffferent reasons causing this, one of them could be a mismatch in versions of `@prisma/client` and `@prisma/cli`.